# Hierarchical clustering: must have n>=2 objects to cluster in r

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I'm following this [guide](http://dataaspirant.com/2018/01/08/hierarchical-clustering-r/), using readxl to insert my [data](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ajz8Bxb5itpxhDx5EsRaUShyo8ld). I want to use hierarchical clustering to group the studies together and there are 12 observations. Some studies have missing data and some studies have no data at all. So following the guide:

```
> df <-read_excel("MDO.xlsx")
> df <- na.omit(df)
> df <- scale(df)
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
> d <- dist(df, method = "euclidean")
Warning message:
In dist(df, method = "euclidean") : NAs introduced by coercion
> hc1 <- hclust(d, method = "complete" )
Error in hclust(d, method = "complete") : 
 must have n >= 2 objects to cluster
```

I'm fairly new to R and have never used clustering before so I'm not sure exactly how to fix these errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Read data:
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("MDO.xlsx")
# Convert to data.frame
df <- as.data.frame(df)
# Remove rows when all is na
df <- df[!apply(is.na(df[, -1]), 1, all),]
# Scale the columns
df[, -1] <- apply(df[, -1], 2, scale)
# Distance and cluster
d <- dist(df, method = "euclidean")
hc1 <- hclust(d, method = "complete" )
plot(hc1)
```

[image]

Comment: Works well, can you explain why you need to scale the columns and how does r deal with the missing values?

Comment: Also since there are 10 studies and we remove the rows which are all na, the numbers don't correspond to the study number. How would you go about labelling them?

Comment: I used scale because you use it in your example, this is used so that all the columns have the same weight in the calculation of the distance. The label of the chart matches the name of the rows in your table (use this before calculating the distance: rownames (df) <- df [, 1]).